# C - Getting string checking it and making it a double

Tags: c, string, error-handling, double

```
double_q_CPUTime;
double temp;

printf("Please enter q: CPU Time: ");

scanf("%lf", &temp);

if(input_validator('a',temp) == 'T') {
    q_CPUTime = temp;
}
else {
    printf("Invalid input");
}
```

I can't work out how to handle errors for the above code. I basically would like to

1. Prompt user for input
2. Validate user input to see if only contains 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 or . basically to make sure it is a double
3. Then if it is a double I would like to convert the save the value in temp to q_CPUTIME
4. And if it's not a double then show the user an error message saying "invalid input"

I would like this to loop until the user enters a valid double.

I've tried this many ways and the code at the top of this is my best attempt. I just can't come up with a way to implement this.

Every time I've tried, even if the user enters a string it will just save some weird number to the double causing my calculations later on in the program to break or even C to crash.

Apologies about my last very vague post on this topic.

(I've looked at checking each character entered but then had problems transferring it in to a double)

Comment: Why are you comparing what input_validator returns to 'T'?  Are you using 'T' as a stand-in for boolean true?

Comment: Yes , as c doenst have booleans i thought that would be the best way...

Comment: You left `'0'` out of your list of digits.  You also ignore scientific notation: `1.2e34`.  But you can't validate a string representing a double just by seeing what characters it contains.  `"123.456"` is valid; `"12.34.56"` is not.  `strtod()` takes care of all this for you; no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @user983969: "c doesn't have booleans' is an oversimplification.  You should read section 9 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use strtod; it checks double overflow/underflow also like:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

  double d;
  char *e,s[100];

  fgets(s,100,stdin); if( s[strlen(s)-1]=='\n' ) s[strlen(s)-1]=0;
  errno=0;
  d=strtod(s,&e);
  if( *e || errno==EINVAL || errno==ERANGE )
    puts("error");
  else
    printf("d=%f\n",d);
```

Comment: Best answer so far, would you be able to expalin what the *e is doing? i undestand the rest of code the just dont see why the char *e is releveant?

Comment: *e means the char, where strtod stops the scan. *e means *e!='\0' and that means, strtod has stopped not on the end of the string, eg. on a non digit char -> error

Answer (score 1):

Just check the return value of scanf to detect errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
        double input = 0.0;

        // scanf() returns the number of correctly read input items
        //In our case that's 1
        if (scanf("%lf", &input) == 1) {
                printf("%f", input);
        } else {
                printf("input error");
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of "if(scanf())" I would "if(scanf()==1)" to compare explicitly to the number of fields that are expected to be read.

Comment: The big problem with the `*scanf` family of functions is that if the input is a syntactically valid number that won't fit in the target type (for example `1.0e999999`), then the behavior is undefined.  There is no mechanism for detecting or handling numeric overflow.  Another issue is that using `scanf()` to read a number from stdin leaves whatever followed it in input.  If you type `123.45` followed by `Enter`, then newline character will be left waiting to be processed.  At least that can be worked around.

Comment: Look at the 3rd answer, i thing personally that is the best way to solve this problem would you agree?

Answer (score 0):

Scrap everything after your "Please enter..." printf.  Read in a string from the user.  Use strtod to both convert it to a double and check if it is a valid double string.

Comment: You wrote strtof; you meant strtod (fixed).